# XeLaTeX - using TTF fonts in equations

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am using XeLaTeX in combination with `fontspec` package which enables me to use TTF fonts:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

    \setmainfont{freeserif}[
    Path=./oblika/pisave/,
    Extension=.ttf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    ItalicFont=*-italic]
```

But in math mode text remains unchanged:

[image]

Is there a way to use TTF fonts in mathmode?

Comment: Have you checked out `mathspec`?

Comment: Not yet! Does it work in a similar way? I guess I will read the documentation on CTAN first and then report back.

Comment: or  `unicode-math` if you want o use opentype math fonts

Comment: I think `mathspec` could serve me better. I don't know yet. It is too often to say as I am newbie with these two packages...

Comment: @71GA uniocde-math is better if the font is a math font (that is, has an OpenType MATH table internally) it does not work at all with a normal text font. Conversely mathspec is better if you are trying to use a standard text font in math

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using FreeSerif as a text font; it has wide coverage of Unicode, at the expense of being just a collection of fonts and symbols not particularly studied to go along well.

Comment: @egreg Well I am using FreeSerif as it is the closest as I can get to Times new Roman... Maybee Liberation Serif is also good, but it isn't quite there... Letter "A" is different...

Comment: STIX *is* Times and crafted with greater care, like TeX Gyre Termes.

Comment: @TeXnician thank you. Your answer suits my needs best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unicode-math` which is `fontspec`, but for math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

    $This\ is\ typeset\ in\ math\ font\ STIX\ Two$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Or TeX Gyre Termes Math, or XITS Math, if STIX Two Math is not available.

Comment: @egreg yes, TeX Gyre fonts are good, having both text and math variants.

Answer (score 0):

Another version is to use `mathspec`. This package especially enables you to use text fonts (which might not even support maths) as math font. To make this text font the default math font, but use another font for some specific fonts you can use the `range` option (f.i. to specify another calligraphic font, ...)

To show that it works, I'll use the not-really-math-font Calibri.

[image: calibri]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Calibri}
\setallsansfonts{Calibri}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Calibri}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    \[
        \sum Calibri~is~fine~\mathrm{here}
    \]
\end{document}
```